# Want to replace Ubuntu 12.04 with 14.04 without using internet

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, live-usb

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed on my Dell Vostro laptop. Is there a way to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.o4 using the same disk space which is used by 12.04 currently. My Ubuntu 12.04 DOES NOT connect to internet through wired or wireless connection. So I need a solution where I can boot from USB for upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

you could just get any iso and get it in a usb making it by disk creator and then just boot up BIOS and change the boot selection to usb first and then reboot and download. easy